# How to serve mp4 streaming video on Google App Engine Blobstore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, video-streaming, mp4, blobstore

I am using GAE to serve large files, and I can successfully serve mp3 using a simple `blobstoreService.serve(key, res);` If I put the resource url in the browser, the media control will appear and/or the media player will start, and the music will start before the download is complete.

However, when I put a mp4 url in the Chrome, the control appears but nothing happens. Here are what I have done:

1. no content disposition to avoid download. If I put the content disposition, then the browser will download the video.
2. I even used ffmpeg to convert the video and put -movflags faststart option there but no difference.
3. I also set the response header to `Accept-Ranges:bytes` to the first request and I have observed that the next request still asks for full 75MB range.  Should I only serve partially even though the browser asks for all?
4. Or how to let the browser know that I wanted to serve piece by piece so the requests will have ranges.  Is content-length necessary?  Should I process the HEAD request? I believe right now my servlet only processes GET.
5. my url is like http://www.somesite.com/serve?folder=aa&file=ok.MP4  the Chrome console shows that only 1MB is downloaded and then it stopped
6. The html code looks like below except my GAE url is the src. The example mp4 works but if my gae link is there, it doesn't show video at all.

   **<video width="640" controls="">
   <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
   </video>**

### Question

What exactly are needed to do on GAE server side to serve the video using streaming?

### Answer

The marked answer has sufficient information on how to serve the mp4 file and it also gives a live web page for demo.  From that demo, I was able to tell that my site could serve an mp4 file as long as the Chrome browser could decode it. The problem I encountered was due to the codec used in ffmpeg wasn't recognized by Chrome.  Changed to H.264, everything worked fine.

Here is one example of the ffmpeg command line, where OK.MTS is the camcorder file, output1.mp4 is to be uploaded:

```
ffmpeg -i ok.MTS -codec:v libx264 -profile:v baseline -preset slow -b:v 500k -maxrate 800k -bufsize 1000k -vf scale=-1:432 -threads 0 -b:a 96k output1.mp4
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Is your handler putting the correct Content-Type in the response headers? You need to be setting "Content-Type:video/mp4" for the video to play correctly.

[Here](http://audio-test.appspot.com/) is a test site I wrote on App Engine that plays mp3, ogg and mp4 files from Cloud Storage and the BlobStore.

[Here](http://audio-test.appspot.com/render_video_mp4?session_key=MTc0ODMwMDI=) is a link to an mp4 file in the BlobStore that uses serve() to return the file. When I paste this link into chrome the content plays correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your site.  It's weird.  Mine has all the similar response, except that the Chrome only downloads 1MB and stopped. Another file stopped at 1.1M.

Comment: One thing I noticed is that although I explicitly tried to setContentLength, the header doesn't have that.

Comment: I don't think we let you set that header when using serve(), because the response is chunked.

Comment: Thank you for this info.  If just use bsService.serve(key, res), how does the blob service see the range?  I use Chrome and I can see the response range matches the request range, although the chunk stops after a few MB.  Maybe my files are too big? is 75MB too big?

Comment: Please read the docs, it specifically mentions how to serve a range: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/#Java_Serving_a_blob

Comment: After I downloaded your mp4 and uploaded to my site, I found that mine can stream as well.  I am guessing the file I created using ffmpeg is not compatible with streaming